# Select from database after string entered in AJAX (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, ajax

This is probably simple, but I'm unsure of which tools to use for the job. Basically, the user needs to enter either an account number or name (same text box), and when they click search their account details will appear below in detailsviews and gridviews. What tools do I use so all this can happen on the same page?

Comment: This question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Sounds like a case for an UpdatePanel with a Nested GridView (bound to a datasource). Common scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [stored procedures](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/storedprocedure.htm), don't even think about going down the route of creating in-line SQL, especially when account details are involved.  I'm assuming your database is MSSQL?  If so [this link should help](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/storedprocedure.htm).  From the stored procedure you'll be returned a datatable, to which you can bind your gridview for displaying to the user.